# Средний показатель людей N лет

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Делаю локализацию сайта.
Мне нужно сформулировать заголовок

> Средняя оценка людей N лет

так, чтобы можно было вставить любое N цифрами.
Данный вариант не подходит для N = 21.

Можно ли это как-то лучше сказать?

> Средний показатель для N-летнего возраста?
>   Средняя оценка для N-летних?

Comment: Что мешает сделать условие на вид числа? Заканчивается на 1, пишете "года", иначе "лет"

Comment: Мне нравится Ваш вариант  "Средняя оценка для N-летних"

Comment: @Glinka, я только перевожу, а кодируют другие. К сожалению, качество русского перевода у них не имеет большого приоритета. Поэтому я стараюсь сделать как можно лучше в существующих условиях, чтоб не ждать изменения кода.

Answer (score 2):

> Средний показатель для N-летнего возраста? 
>   Средняя оценка для N-летних?

Первое не пойдет, ибо "...летний возраст" это здесь излишество.

Второе ("для N-летних") отдает разговорным стилем, а подозреваю, что тут впролне серьезный контекст (зря вы о том умолчали). Но коль скоро ничего другого в голову не приходит, можно оставить ну как меньшее из зол, что ли.

Хотя я лично не вижу ничего критичного и в формулировке "для людей 21 лет". Она тоже шершавая, но тут уж ничего не поделаешь, нет в русском такой проcтой формы, как "They are 21".

Хотя строго правильно было бы сказать что-то типа *"для **возрастной категории** от 21 до 22 лет"*.

UPD

Подумалось. Если контекст действительно не слишком серьёзный, почему не сказать ***"Средняя оценка (для) тех, кому N"***?